# invalid characters appears in DDL when exp command used to export DDL

Tags: oracle, shell

I want to export DDL and its grants using exp command

But the issue i am getting is : invalid characters are printing in file

I just want particular Table DDL and grants

**command :**

```
exp username/password@servicename file=/d/demo/file.txt TABLES=employees grants=y rows=n statistics=none direct=y
```

Comment: Please post your shell script code and the SQL you are using to get the DDL. We can't really troubleshoot what we can't see.

Comment: The output from `exp` is a binary file. You can't print that. If you want to get the DDL as a SQL (plain text) script, use `dbms_metadata`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if table as 800 column then this query does not print entire DDL it truncate the DDL export

Comment: `dbms_metadata` does not  return "truncated" values. It's the SQL client that you are using that doesn't return the full result. Check the configuration of your tools

Comment: As an alternative to dbms_metadata, if you used data pump instead of legacy exp/imp (why aren't you?) you could use the 'sqlfile' option with impdp.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to look that up.